# ASP Net core ajax not recognizing passed data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have controller method which looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateNew(string Naslov, int KorisnikID, int GrupaID, string Tekst)
{
    //Some code
}
```

Ajax function that is calling this is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Story/CreateNew",
    contentType: "application.json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "Naslov": $("#Naslov").val(),
        "KorisnikID": @Context.Request.Cookies["kid"],
        "GrupaID": $("#GrupaID").val(),
        "Tekst": $("#Tekst .ql-editor").html()
    }),
    success: function (message) {
        var elements = message.split("-");

        if (elements[0] == "success") {
            window.location.href = '/Clanak?ID' + elements[1];
        }
        else {
            alert(message);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr + " " + status + " " + error);
    }
});
```

Method is entered but all parameters are null.

Here is how post method looks like in browser inspect
[image]

Also when i change it to GET it works (but i need post since i have problem with length of string)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was you cannot use POST method same way you do with get and you needed to provide it `anti-forgery` token to it.

Full solution could be found [here](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/)